# How to find the field lines of a vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help finding the field lines of a vector field. I hesitant if the procedure and solution is correct.

The vector field is
$$\mathbf{F}(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf{\hat x}+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf{\hat{y}}$$
So I should solve the equation
$$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))=\frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}, \quad \text{where} \quad \mathbf{r}(t)=x(t)\mathbf{\hat x}+y(t)\mathbf{\hat y}
$$
Therefore I have the equations$$
\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2} \tag{1}
$$
$$
\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \tag{2}
$$
The first one is
$$
\frac{x^2+y^2}{-y}dx=dt
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow t=-y-\frac{x^3}{3y}+C_1 \tag{3}
$$
And the second equation is
$$
\frac{x^2+y^2}{x}dy=dt
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow t=x+\frac{y^3}{3x}+C_2 \tag{4}
$$
And let $(3)=(4)$ so
$$
-y-\frac{x^3}{3y}+C_1=
x+\frac{y^3}{3x}+C_2
$$
Let $-(C_1-C_2)=C_3$ so
$$
y+\frac{x^3}{3y}+x+\frac{y^3}{3x}+C_3=0
$$
Is this correct? How can i interpret this equation in the $(x,y,z)$-space?

Comment: you can write a function $z=y+ \frac {x^3}{3y}+x+\frac {y^3}{3x}+C_3$ and take the level curve at $z=0$

Answer (score 1):

From your (1) and (2) equation you can get:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{y}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how you obtained $(3)$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$. In any case $(3)$ and $(4)$ are false. The solution curves are in fact concentric circles, and you obtained third degree curves.

Note that your field is nothing else than $\nabla{\rm arg}$, hence the field vectors are orthogonal to the level lines of ${\rm arg}$, which are rays emanating from the origin.